# Link between Ramsey Theory, random graphs and spin glasses

Tags: reference-request, ramsey-theory, random-graphs

As all three theories study the emergence of order, it would be natural if there were some links between:

- Ramsey theory;
- random graphs;
- spin glasses.

Is there a textbook or an article that describes the relation between the three or tries to find it?

Looks like there is an article about Ramsey properties of random graphs:
T. Luczak, A. Rucinski, and B. Voigt. *Ramsey properties of random graphs*. Journal of
Combinatorial Theory, Series B, 56(1):55  68, 1992.

There is also a [Randomized version of Ramsey theorem](http://www.cadmo.ethz.ch/as/people/alumni/thomahen/publications/ramsey-rsa.pdf).